# cancel stdout of a process that started using os.execvp()

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, execvp

I'm trying to start a process with `os.execvp` but I want to cancel its stdout.

I have tried to change `sys.stdout` to `os.devnull` but it didn't work.

```py
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
os.execvp(proc_path, proc_args)
```

I also tried to use `os.dup2` to change the file description and it didn't work as well.

```
STDOUT = 1

fdout = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_WRONLY)
os.dup2(fdout, STDOUT)
os.execvp(proc_path, proc_args)
```

Do you know any better way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel"? Is there any particular reason you are not using `subprocess` instead, where these things are easy to control?

Comment: Not in a place where I can test, but does it work if you simply `sys.stdout.close()`?

Comment: I mean to redirect the output in a way it wont be shown on the terminal. Im trying to trace the syscalls the process makes- I dont know if `subprocess` works for that.

Comment: `sys.stdout.close()` doesn't work.

Comment: `subprocess` differs from the `os.exec*` family in that it creates a new process, rather than replace the current one. If that's acceptable, try `subprocess.run([proc_path] + proc_args, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)`

Comment: In my case I need to replace the current process- To trace its syscalls.  I create a child process which I trace from the parent one. When I make a new process as you suggested, I lose all the syscalls Im trying to trace.